# Cannot connect remote linux host by Sunlogin after a reboot without logining in GUI on host first

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, login-screen

I'm using [Sunlogin](https://sunlogin.oray.com/en/embed/software.html) to control a host Ubuntu remotely (server) by my Windows (client). They are both installed with Sunlogin and are connected to web.

**Problem**

After I reboot the server and wait for enough time to make sure the server is online (the notification saying the server is online has been received), then I click the `Desktop` button to connect the server but the client just stuck in the [interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVAJS.png) with no error message occurs.

Only after I login in my account in GUI on server at least once (operate on the server instead of client) can I connect the server successfully. But the advantage of remote control is control **remotely**, isn't it? I don't want to go to the server every time I need to reboot it.

**What I have tried**

I have searched for the manual of the product but found nothing. I don't know if this is because I miss some configuration of Sunlogin or if this is due to some Linux security mechanism.